# Historical debugging

Tags: debugging, ide

I have to debug a very big program, which takes around 10 minutes until it reaches the most important debugging state. I just want to modify some values in this part of the program, but sometimes I would like to go back and modify them again, like travelling to the past. As far as I know it is called historical debugging. Reading some info it seems it has been implemented in Visual Studio 2010. But I only use Eclipse or Xcode or vi :)

I wonder if know some other software with these capabilites.

By the way, I ask about your opinion, do you think it will be possible, once I reach this state of my program, to modify some small part of the code, after the breakpoint, and compile it again (supposing it does not affect to the past execution and code) so I can test it without recompiling?

Thanks

Comment: Any specific language in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Also discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221806/debugging-backwards)

Mostly only available for interpreted languages like Java ([ODB](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/)). And I am not sure if you can continue from some point of execution with changed data.

Have you tried to set watch point in Eclipse that would break as soon as a variable reach a specific value? This means your code executes normally until it breaks your data and execution stops so that you can see how you code got to this point.